# Is it possible to order an array of integers in linear time?

Tags: sorting

The other day I was reading blogs about interviews for internships in Google and Microsoft, and I read that one of the questions was how to order an array of integers in linear time.

I thought the best way for ordering stuff is O(n log(n)) like Mergesort or Quicksort, but know I'm not sure. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there must have been some more constraints to the question. Example, if the array consists of just few repeating numbers `[1 3 2 6 3 1 2]` you can use `counting sort` to do this in linear time but it will use more space.

Another algorithm you can look out for is the `Dutch National Flag` algorithm which can sort 3 repeating numbers in linear time. Other than this, I don't think (ignorance is not bliss here :P) I know of a way to sort a normal array in linear time.

Even if you use `Radix sort` it will take up `O(m * n)` but if `m <<< n` you can argue that its approximately `O(n)`

Answer (score 2):

`O(n lg n)` is the best you can do for *comparision-based* sorts, which don't require you to know anything about the items you are sorting other than how you compare one to another. Sorting a list of integers of bounded size (i.e., each integer is at most `K`, where `K` is independent of `n`) is a more specialized problem, so you can use a more specialized algorithm that runs faster than `O(n lg n)` (such as radix sort).